# How to extract an element from an excel file in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

Let's say I have the following sheet in an excel file :

```
First row
142   15
second row
258   30
third row
789   35
```

I am writing a MATLAB script which at first extracts the number `789` (because the same number was found in another sheet of the same file). Now I also want to extract the number in same row as my number `789` but in the second column: here it's `35`.

I was looking for a way to find the index of an element knowing its value. This way I could find the row and coloumn of my known value `789` and use it to extract the corresponding number, here `35`.

Here is the code i used for extracting a redundant number in both sheets

```
firsttasks = xlsread('myfile1','Feuil1', 'A1:A3');  
secondtaskes = xlsread('myfile1', 'Feuil2', 'A1:A3');
Lia = ismember(firsttaskes,secondtasks,'rows');
for i=1:3
    if Lia(i) == 1
        found = firsttasks(i);


    end
end
```

Comment: How have you imported your excel file in matlab?

Comment: No i actually created it using matlab

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], so that we know what you are exactly doing?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to explain well. In fact, I have one excel file containing two sheets. Each sheet contains some numbers in the first column ( lets say Ids of some tasks) and the second column contains the minutes corresponding to each task. First, i look for the same tasks that are present in both sheets(so same ID) then i want to extract the corresponding minutes in order to calculate the difference. Lets say the task 789 took us 35 minutes in the first sheet and 41 minutes in the second, i want to extract 35 and 41 then calculate the difference.

Comment: I think I understand what your overall goal is, but I try to understand which part you have already solved (and how)? So, we can start from that point to help you further. Providing us your relevant matlab code would be a good idea.

Comment: I added the relevant matlab code to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution for this task:

```
firsttasks = xlsread('myfile1','Feuil1');
secondtaskes = xlsread('myfile1', 'Feuil2');
IDmatch = [(1:size(firsttasks,1))*bsxfun(@eq,firsttasks(:,1),secondtaskes(:,1).')
    1:size(secondtaskes,1)];
IDmatch(:,IDmatch(1,:)==0) = [];
t = [firsttasks(IDmatch(1,:),1)...
    abs(firsttasks(IDmatch(1,:),2)-secondtaskes(IDmatch(2,:),2))];
```

Here `t(k,1)` is the ID and `t(k,2)` is the difference in time for this ID. There are no `nan`s, since we don't compare the values of the unmatched ID.

This solution does not handle a case where one ID is present twice or more in an of the sheets since you did not define what happens in such a case (if possible).

---

**How it works?**

We search for equal IDs between the 2 lists by comparing all possible combinations of IDs between the lists. This is done with the function [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) that applies a binary element-wise operation on two inputs while expanding their singleton dimension to match each other. When the input to this function are two vectors, in size 1-by-m and n-by-1, the result is an m-by-n matrix, where each element is the result of the operation on a different combination of elements from both vectors. Let's look at an example:

After importing the data from excel, it looks like this:

```
firsttasks =
   142    15
   258    30
   789    35
    76    32
    94    15
    46    48
    32    97

secondtaskes =
   142    23
   258    76
   789    34
    46    75
    32    21
    67    48
```

With the vectors of the IDs `firsttasks(:,1)` and `secondtaskes(:,1)` we do the comparison (note that the second vector is transposed), and get the following output:

```
>> bsxfun(@eq,firsttasks(:,1),secondtaskes(:,1).')
ans =
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

In this matrix, each element in place (i,j) indicates a match between the ID in `firsttasks(i,1)` and `secondtaskes(j,1)`.

Next, we multiply the indices of `firsttasks` by this matrix, to get the row numbers in `firsttasks` that have a match, and a zeros in case there isn't:

```
>> (1:size(firsttasks,1))*bsxfun(@eq,firsttasks(:,1),secondtaskes(:,1).')
ans =
     1     2     3     6     7     0
```

Note that the indices of the result above stand for the rows in `secondtaskes`, so the number 6 indicates that row **4** in `secondtaskes` match row **6** in `firsttasks`. Now we concatenate them vertically with the indices of `secondtaskes` so we have both indices together:

```
>> IDmatch = [(1:size(firsttasks,1))*bsxfun(@eq,firsttasks(:,1),secondtaskes(:,1).')
    1:size(secondtaskes,1)]
IDmatch =
     1     2     3     6     7     0
     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

And we remove all cases where there is no match (i.e. there is a zero in the first line:

```
>> IDmatch(:,IDmatch(1,:)==0) = []
IDmatch =
     1     2     3     6     7
     1     2     3     4     5
```

We take all the IDs that we found to have a match:

```
>> firsttasks(IDmatch(1,:),1)
ans =
   142
   258
   789
    46
    32
```

and concatenate them horizontally with all the differences in their corresponding values at the second column:

```
>> abs(firsttasks(IDmatch(1,:),2)-secondtaskes(IDmatch(2,:),2))
ans =
     8
    46
     1
    27
    76
```

And so we get:

```
>> t = [firsttasks(IDmatch(1,:),1)...
    abs(firsttasks(IDmatch(1,:),2)-secondtaskes(IDmatch(2,:),2))]
t =
   142     8
   258    46
   789     1
    46    27
    32    76
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please give more explanations because i did not understand the code above. I also tried to apply it just for testing and it gave me the following error :Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Untitled (line 4)
IDmatch = [1:7;(1:7)*bsxfun(@eq,firsttasks(:,1),secondtaskes(:,1).').'];

Comment: I should also clarify that the tasks are not in the same order in both sheets

Comment: @F.Lin see my edit for fixing the error and an explanation of the method.